# ¿Se usa 'guácala' fuera de México?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, méxico, interjecciones

En español mexicano, cuando uno siente algo repugnante es típico usar una palabra onomatopeica: 'guácala' (imita el sonido de vomitar). Es equivalente a decir 'yuck' en inglés.

¿Qué tan común es 'guácala' por el mundo hispanohablante?

¿Se usan otras palabras en otros lugares?

Comment: En Nicaragua se usa igualmente.

Comment: A como dice @jrdioko en Nicaragua se usa igual.

Comment: No entiendo por qué razón *guácala* es una onomatopeya del vómito. No me suena así.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En Ecuador se utiliza la palabra. Sospecho que el show de televisión mejicano '[El Chavo del Ocho](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0229889/?ref_=sr_1)' pudo haber llegado a tener un rol en su adopción. Recuerdo que el personaje de '[la Chilindrina](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0028991/?ref_=tt_cl_t1)' lo usaba bastante seguido.

Comment: +1 Interesante lo de la posible influencia del Chavo del Ocho. Recuerdo también que se usaba mucho esa palabra ahí.

Answer (score 6):

En España no se usa "guácala" ni nada similar.

Algunas onomatopeyas comunes para expresar asco son "puaj" o "aj".

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia también se usa, (o se usaba) hace unos años era muy común escucharla, ya casi no la he escucho -no quiere decir, que aún no se utilize-, pero sí tiene la misma connotación de asco, disgusto.

Comment: Entonces, ?cual onomatopeya se usa en colombia para expresar asco?

Comment: Hmmm... pues yo sí que la sigo oyendo en Colombia y bastante seguido.

Comment: Creo que la onomatopeya más común que conozco donde vivo, -no generalizaré en toda Colombia porque sería erróneao- es ugh.

Answer (score 3):

Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.

---

#### Sí se usa en...

- Chile (también se usa *guácatela* y *puaj*)
- Colombia
- Ecuador
- Guatemala (también se usa *guácatela*)
- México
- Nicaragua
- Venezuela (también se usa *guácatela*)
- Costa Rica

#### No se usa en...

- España (se usa *puaj* y *aj*)

Comment: En Venezuela se usa mucho, además también se usa guácatela refiriendose a "qué asco"

Comment: En Chile también se usa, como también es usado `guácatela`, tal como menciona @Santiago. Otra palabra (interjección) que acá se puede usar con el mismo sentido es: `¡Puaj!`.

Comment: En mis experiencias en Colombia (más que nada en la isla de San Andrés y con la gente allí), todavía está en uso común -- es una palabra que escucho mucho entre mi esposa y su familia, al menos.

Comment: En España no la usamos, o al menos no la he escuchado nunca.

Comment: En Guatemala es muy común entre los niños, especialmente para referirse a comida que no les gusta. Entre adultos "que asco" se escucha más, pero mucha gente usa el **guácala** todavía.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. ¿Se usa 'guácala' fuera de México?

Según el DAMER, se usa en los siguientes países:

> #### [¡guácala!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gu%C3%A1cala)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, PR, Co, Ve, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py.* Expresa desagrado, asco o rechazo. pop + cult → espon. (**¡huácala!**).

Y las palabras derivadas así:

> #### [¡huácala!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=hu%C3%A1cala)
>
> **I.    1.**    *Ho, ES, RD, PR, Ec, Pe, Bo, Py.* **¡guácala!**
>
> #### [¡juácata!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=ju%C3%A1cata)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *ES, Ni.* Expresa asco.
>
> #### [¡fácata!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=f%C3%A1cata)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Ho.* Expresa rechazo o asco.

> #### [¡guácatela!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gu%C3%A1catela)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Mx, Ho, ES, CR; Pa, Ec,* juv; *Ch,* cult → espon. Expresa asco o desagrado. pop. (**¡guácatelas!**).
>
> #### [¡guácatelas!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gu%C3%A1catelaa)
>
> **I.    1.**    *Mx, CR.* **¡guácatela!**

Además hay el sustantivo similar:

> #### [guácara](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gu%C3%A1cara)
>
> **I.    1.**    f. *Mx.* Vómito. pop.

---

## 2. ¿Se usan otras palabras en otros lugares?

Otras palabras no relatos que se usan en otros países son:

> #### [¡atatay!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=atatay)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Co:SO.* Expresa disgusto. pop + cult → espon.
>    **2.** *Ec, Pe.* Expresa asco. pop + cult → espon. (**atatao; ¡atatau!; ¡tatay!**).
>
> #### [¡tatay!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tatay)
>
> **I.    1.**    *Co:SO, Ec.* **¡atatay!**
>
> #### [¡atatau!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=atatau) <sub>(Del quech. *atatau*).</sub>
>
> **I.    1.**    *Pe.* **¡atatay!**
>
> #### [atatao.](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=atatao)
>
> **II.   1.**    interj. *Pe.* **atatay.**

> #### [¡fuchi!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fuchi)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, Ve, Ec, Pe; Co, Bo, Py.* pop ^ desp. Expresa desagrado o rechazo. (**¡fuche!**).
>    **3.** *PR.* **¡fo!**, expresa desagrado.
>
> #### [¡fuche!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fuche)
>
> **I.    1.**    *Ni.* **¡fuchi!**, expresa rechazo.

> #### [¡fo!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fo)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Pa, Cu, RD, PR, Co, Ve.* Expresa desagrado o rechazo por algo que huele mal. pop. ◆ **¡fuchi!**

> #### [¡ish!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=3tzOr4npNx0AOeH9DHy)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *ES.* Expresa asco o rechazo.

> #### [¡eco!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=19gaxbImNx0AO5kD7XG%7CNO67qicggx0A9R0HobV%7CEvJmvthDHx0AlWyWcRV)
>
> **II.   1.**    interj. *Ve.* Expresa asco o repugnancia hacia algo.

> #### [¡gas!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=9ynWk3DCWx0ACaib9v7%7CcLXyvHGLGx0ATqDZc4L)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *Co.* Expresa asco.

> #### [¡asco!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=PTzeUGQGyx0A4P3hFAL%7CI1rNKfimcx0APAdYKfY)
>
> **I.    1.**    interj. *RD, Co, Ve, Ec.* Expresa repugnancia.