# Equivalente de "guácala" en el español europeo

Tags: modismos, diferencias-regionales, españa, interjecciones

Dejarle a mi hijo mayor la tablet con el YouTube Kids no deja de ser un filón de preguntas con los vídeos que va descubriendo. Hace tiempo vio uno que tenía una canción que decía más o menos así:

> —Do you like broccoli?
>   —Yes, I do.
>   —Do you like ice cream?
>   —Yes, I do.
>   —Do you like broccoli ice cream?
>   —No, I don't! Yuck!

Hace poco descubrió la versión traducida al español de Hispanoamérica, que traducía la última frase como:

> —¡No me gusta! ¡Guácala!

Teníais que ver las caras de asombro de los tres que estábamos allí cuando oímos eso de "guácala". Luego ya me fui al diccionario de americanismos y [descubrimos lo que significaba](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=gu%C3%A1cala), y cómo y dónde se usa (y luego aquí en el sitio aprendí [el origen de la palabra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8794/12637)).

Existen otras palabras similares, también de uso en Hispanoamérica: tenemos *[ufa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zoxaQ)*, *[atatay](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=atatay)*, *[fuchi](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fuchi)* y más, incluyendo algunas variantes de las ya mencionadas.

Estas expresiones me resultan coloridas a la par que interesantes, pues me hicieron pensar en qué expresiones usamos en el español europeo en casos similares. Yo en la canción habría usado [*aj*, o *puaj*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2776/12637), que no aparecen en el diccionario pero sí en el CORDE:

> *Hieden los esclavos, ¡puaj!, hieden a carne hedionda [...].*
>
> Arturo Uslar Pietri, "Las lanzas coloradas", 1931 (Venezuela).

O sencillamente *qué asco*, que no me resulta tan expresiva como las otras.

Así pues, aparte de las ya citadas, ¿tenemos en España alguna expresión similar a las Hispanoamericanas para expresar repulsa, asco o desagrado? Mejor si aparece en el DLE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el DLE, la única que he visto que no está marcada como regionalismo, es "**fo**":

> **[fo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I8eHLnb)**
>
> 1. interj. U. para expresar asco.

Sólo hay un pequeño detalle... y es que no he oído a nadie, en toda mi vida, usar esa palabra (para eso, al menos).

Las que sí que he oído y uso siempre, son **puaj** o **buaj**, ya apuntadas por ti.
Es cierto que no aparecen en el DLE, pero [según el fichero de la RAE](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_P/LETRA_P_PDF/PUAJ/00001052.pdf), la propia Academia la usó en [su Boletín](http://www.rae.es/boletines/brae) en algún momento.

Quizá sea el momento de proponer su inclusión en el diccionario. *EDIT*: Cosa que finalmente hice, por cierto. Otra cosa es que acepten dicha propuesta :D

Comment: Yo tampoco jamás he oído ni leído *fo* y me ha sorprendido que *puaj* no aparezca en el diccionario

Comment: En algunas regiones de Colombia la he oído para expresar que un olor es desagradable.

Answer (score 2):

Existen las onomatopeyas:

> #### [uf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b0zBgLN)
>
> `Voz onomat.`
>   2. interj. Indica repugnancia.

> #### [puf](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ub3kd2L|Ub5tin5)
>
> `Voz onomat.`
>   1. interj. U. para denotar molestia o repugnancia causada por malos olores o cosas nauseabundas.

> #### [pu](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UXyHgWO)
>
> 1. interj. puf<sup>1</sup>.

Y aunque no se reconoce en el DLE, en un diccionario más antiguo tenemos la interjección muy común:

> **¡PUAH!** interj. **¡Puf!**
>
> - 1917 Alemany Y Bolufer